# Help Understanding Gaussian Particle Distribution

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

I have a simple enough problem. I want to mathematically describe a Gaussian particle distribution of $N$ total particles with a spot size of 0.1 (sigma). I need a function that will tell me the amount of particles in a transverse position $x$, i.e. how many particles there are in a bin kind of. But, the distribution should meet three physical requirements:

1. When integrated in all space (from -Infinity to +Infinity) the result should be N.
2. The spot size of the distribution is sigma (0.1, for example).
3. The values of $N$ at any given $x$ should not exceed the total number of particles $N$.

Now, of course the standard equation for a Gaussian is:

$$
\ N(x) = \frac{N} {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \,.
$$

But, this satisfies condition 1 and 2 but not 3! I need an equation that describes the distribution in real space (meaning that for any $x$ value, it should give the number of particles in that transverse slice) but I am confused on how I to go about doing that.

Or is even possible to meet all three conditions with a Gaussian distribution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the motivation behind condition 3? You realize that if you confine N particles to a region of radius .1, the density there will be higher than N, right?

Comment: The motivation is being able to calculate the number of particles in a infinitestimally small bin for a gaussian-ly distributed ensemble. For example, if I want to know how many particles are in the bin at x=0, if it is N, as it is shown in the above gaussian distribution, then that means all my particles are located at x=0! Not something I want.

Comment: Ok, so you are misinterpreting what the value of the distribution function means. See garyp's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that $N(x)/N$ is a probability density, not a probability.  You can see that from the units:  $N/\sigma$  has units "number per meter".   You have to ask:  How many balls will I find between $x_1$ and $x_2$?

The expected number of balls is calculated from this density:  $$ \bar{N} \approx N(x) \Delta x$$ if $\Delta x = x_2-x_1$ is small enough.  If it's too large, then you have to integrate: $$\bar{N} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} N(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$\bar{N}$ will always be less than $N$.